# jQuery toggle between functions - performed zero, one, two, three ... times

Tags: jquery, function, toggle

I'm experimenting with using jQuery toggle to move between two functions. The results so far have been patchy. Below is the entire code of a trial scenario.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#id').on('click',function(event){
         $(this).toggle(
             function(){console.log('Hide');},
             function(){console.log('Show');}
         );
     });
  });
  </script> 
</head>

<body>
  <div id="id">Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, when I click "Hello" for the first time, nothing appears in the log.

```
[Nothing]
```

On the second click, I get:

```
Hide
```

On the third, it adds:

```
Show
Hide
```

On the fourth, it adds:

```
Hide
Show
Hide
```

On the fifth, it adds:

```
Show
Hide
Show
Hide
```

I trust you can see the pattern :)  Why is it doing this? I've experimented with `.stop(true)` but to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toggle()` is executed on click, so you don't need the `click` event wrapper.

```
$('#id').toggle(
         function(){console.log('Hide');},
         function(){console.log('Show');}
     );
```

Your current code attaches `toggle()` to trigger on the `click` event the first time it is clicked, that is why you don't get anything the first time you click the element.

Comment: Beautiful!  The click was the legacy of trying something different before I started using toggle. Removing the click wrapper solves the problem, provided everything I want on the click occurs within the two toggle functions (which may involve a little duplication). Or I guess I can use .toggle(...).on('click',...), can't I?

Comment: @Nick You could chain `toggle()` and `on()` like that, where the `on()` will be triggered with each click.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question, though, because I want the whole lot to function as an event handler. (I'd forgotten why I started down this track in the first place!)

Comment: I've just realised I'm being an idiot, because this does add an event handler. So I've removed my update to the question! Apologies to you, @alex and any one else suffering along, too :)